# storing elements in a database by using JavaScript in web2py

Tags: javascript, python, sqlite, web2py, web2py-modules

The first thing that I would like to point out is that I am like a nervous programmer or nervous learner. I feel like I want to learn things fast, so I start checking websites and books very quickly and If I feel like what I am reading doesn't satisfy my need then I just close it and start doing something else. I am just wondering if that kind of behavior sounds familiar to you.

I have the following problem. I am just starting to learn how to program in web2py and I need to store javascript input in a sqlite database, so for example I have the following table:

```
db = DAL ('sqlite://storage.sqlite')
db.define_table('company', Field('name', notnull = True, unique = True), format = '%(name)s')
db.define_table(
   'contact',
   Field('name', notnull = True),
   format = '%(name)s'
)

and I have the following script code

li.innerHTML = document.getElementById('task').value;
```

so I need to store that document.getElementById in the database. Can u point out the topics that I need to study in order to accomplish such task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by reading the [jQuery and Ajax](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/11/jquery-and-ajax) chapter of the documentation. In particular, check out the [`ajax` function](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/11/jquery-and-ajax#The-ajax-function).

If the `task` element is a form element with a "name" attribute, you can call the `ajax` function as follows (assuming the name of the form element is "task"):

```
ajax("{{=URL('default', 'insert_task')}}", ['task']);
```

If the `task` element is not a form element, you can instead pass it to web2py via the query string:

```
ajax("{{=URL('default', 'insert_task')}}" + '?task=' + encodeURIComponent(li.innerHTML));
```

Then in the web2py controller, the `insert_task` action would handle the insert:

```
def insert_task():
    db.mytable.insert(task=request.vars.task)
    return 'Success'
```

Note, the `ajax` function takes a third argument, which can be (a) the `id` of an HTML element where the returned value should be inserted, (b) a Javascript function to which the returned value will be passed, or (c) the string ":eval", which will result in the returned value being interpreted as Javascript and evaluated. You can use this argument if you want to display some message on the page or make some change to the display after the insert has completed.

Finally, if the `ajax` function is not adequate for your needs, you can always use `jQuery's` Ajax facilities, or any other Javascript method of making Ajax calls.

Comment: That gives me the feeling that the website is gonna have to refresh to store the new value. The value that I am attempting to add in the database is a list element, so I don't want the whole website to reload.

Comment: No, that's the point of using Ajax -- you can send the data from the browser to the server without refreshing the page. The Ajax call can return some data to the browser, which you could then potentially use to update the page (but it wouldn't reload the page). You might have to spend some time learning about Ajax and using Javascript to update the display in the browser.